# Is there a natural Lie bracket for $\mathfrak X (M) \times C^\infty(M)$ (pairs of vector fields and smooth functions)?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras

Space of smooth vector fields $\mathfrak X(M)$ on a manifold $M$ has a structure of Lie algebra with the bracket being a commutator of two vector fields.

Does cartesian product $\mathfrak X (M) \times C^\infty(M)$ of a space of smooth vector fields $\mathfrak X(M)$ with a space of smooth functions $C^\infty(M)$ on the same manifold naturally form a Lie algebra?

What about $\mathfrak X (M) \times C^\infty(M) \times \ldots \times C^\infty(M)$ ?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe the answer to your question is positive? Could you write something about such a reason?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval If you are still interested, the reason for the question comes from fluid dynamics. Ideal incompressible fluid is described solely by its (divergence-free) velocity field. This system is Hamiltonian with a Lie-Posson bracket based on a Lie bracket of vector fields. If there are additional variables, like energy, the reversible part of evolution is still described by a Poisson bracket. I wondered, if this is still a Lie-Poisson bracket and what is the Lie bracket then for velocity fields coupled with this additional scalar fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\mathfrak g$ is a Lie algebra, and $V$ a representation of $\mathfrak g$, then you can define a Lie algebra structure on $\mathfrak g\oplus V$ by the formula
$$[(X,u),(Y,v)]=([X,Y],X\cdot v-Y\cdot u)$$
This applies to your example via the standard action of vector fields on functions by derivation.

---

Here are the details. The bracket is clearly antisymmetric. We only need to check the Jocaobi identity. If $X,X',X''\in\mathfrak g$ and $v,v',v''\in V$, then
$$\begin{align}
[(X,v),[(X',v'),(X'',v'')]]&=[(X,v),([X',X''],X'\cdot v''-X''\cdot v')\big]\\
&=([X,[X',X'']],X\cdot (X'\cdot v''- X''\cdot v')-[X',X'']\cdot v)\\
&=([X,[X',X'']],X\cdot X'\cdot v''- X\cdot X''\cdot v'\\
&\qquad\qquad -X'\cdot X''\cdot v+X''\cdot X'\cdot v)
\end{align}$$
So for $X,Y,Z\in\mathfrak g$ and $u,v,w\in V$. Then
$$\begin{align}
[(X,u),[(Y,v),(Z,w)]]\\
+\:[(Y,v),[(Z,w),(X,u)]]\\
+\:[(Z,w),[(X,u),(Y,v)]]
\end{align}$$
has its first coordinate equal to
$$[X,[Y,Z]]+[Y,[Z,X]]+[Z,[X,Y]]=0$$
and its second coordinate equal to
$$\begin{align}
&\phantom{+}
  X\cdot Y\cdot w- X\cdot Z\cdot v -Y\cdot Z\cdot u+Z\cdot Y\cdot u\\
&+Y\cdot Z\cdot u- Y\cdot X\cdot w -Z\cdot X\cdot v+X\cdot Z\cdot v\\
&+Z\cdot X\cdot v- Z\cdot Y\cdot u -X\cdot Y\cdot w+Y\cdot X\cdot w
\end{align}$$
which equals $0$, as every term appears along with its opposite.